# Buck Rogers episode with a "OMG humans ate MEAT!" scene

Tags: episode-identification, buck-rogers

What I'm looking for is which episode of this show has a scene I remember.

Buck and a friend crash their fighters in a desert planet. They survive unhurt, look around and the friend says there's no civilization around and if they can't call help fast they'll starve. Buck points at a small animal and says "no we won't". The friend is horrified that people used to eat animals in the 20th century but ends up eating the meat along with Buck out of necessity. This scene establishes that 25th century society is vegetarian.

I asked this same question in TVTropes' YKTS sction, but didn't get a definite answer.

Comment: *"... but ends up eating the meat **along with Buck** out of necessity ... "* Poor Buck! What a horrible way to go!

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThatCameOutWrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scene occurs in the second, feature-length story of the show, [Planet of the Slave Girls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Fo09xotUTg).  In syndication, it was shown as two episodes.  The scene occurs at about 1:07 in the linked YouTube video, shortly after the crash landing, which occurred at the beginning of the second sub-episode.  What happens is not quite as evocative as you describe your memory of it, but that's definitely it.

Comment: That's the one! Hey, look, JACK PALANCE is in that episode!

Comment: Wait a second. There was a piece of dialogue prior to that one where Buck called the other pilot's attention to the animal running around on the ground. It seems that cut doesn't have it but the one I watched in 1980 did. I'd wager they edited it out for the DVD edition.

Comment: Jack Palance had a number of roles in the 1980s showing off his skill playing evil wizards:  also Hawk the Slayer and Outlaw of Gor.  The latter provides one of my favorite MST3K episodes.